# I accidentally deleted themes.xml(night) file. now i want it back to enable dark mode to my app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Can anybody help me to create theme night file.

I tried to create but it overrides the normal themes file

and when I put (night) it gives error of course (ex     `themes.xml`(night)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you need to open the project in Explorer. `PATH_OF_PROJECT\app\src\main\res`

1. Here you will show folder `values` and `values-night`
2. If you didn't show any `values-night` folder, then create it manually.
3. Open `values-night` folder and create file into `values-night` folder as `themes.xml`

Now you can see `themes.xml(night)` in your project. And you can use it